# matplotlib subplots runs very slow only on some workstations

Tags: python, matplotlib, rhel

I'm using matplotlib in scripts on two different RHEL linux workstations (both RHEL 7.9). On one workstation it takes less than a second (0.18s) to call plt.subplots, while the other can take more than 45s!! Below is a simple timing script I used to check the timing. I've tried different versions of matplotlib (via miniconda), but it doesn't seem to make a difference. The workstation that loads plt.subplots slowly should be faster based on specs (see below). Any ideas of other things to check?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Andy

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

fig_time_s = time.time()

fig, ax  = plt.subplots(figsize=(9.0, 4.0), dpi=200)

fig_time_e = time.time()
fig_time  = fig_time_e - fig_time_s
print('FIG TIME: {:7.2f}s'.format(fig_time))
```

---

version of matplotlib:
|# Name                    |Version                   |Build  |Channel
|---|---|---|---|
|matplotlib                |3.2.2                     |    1    |conda-forge
|matplotlib-base           |3.2.2            |py37h30547a4_0    |conda-forge

---

These are the specs of the workstations:

| Property | faster | slower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Architecture: | x86_64 | x86_64 |
| CPU op-mode(s): | 32-bit, 64-bit | 32-bit, 64-bit |
| Byte Order: | Little Endian | Little Endian |
| CPU(s): | 6 | 48 |
| On-line CPU(s) list: | 0-5 | 0-47 |
| Thread(s) per core: | 1 | 2 |
| Core(s) per socket: | 6 | 24 |
| Socket(s): | 1 | 1 |
| NUMA node(s): | 1 | 1 |
| Vendor ID: | GenuineIntel | GenuineIntel |
| CPU family: | 6 | 6 |
| Model: | 63 | 85 |
| Model name: | Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v3 @ 1.90GHz | Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8168 CPU @ 2.70GHz |
| Stepping: | 2 | 4 |
| CPU MHz: | 1899.884 | 1199.871 |
| CPU max MHz: | 1900.0000 | 3700.0000 |
| CPU min MHz: | 1200.0000 | 1200.0000 |
| BogoMIPS: | 3791.33 | 5400.00 |
| Virtualization: | VT-x | VT-x |
| L1d cache: | 32K | 32K |
| L1i cache: | 32K | 32K |
| L2 cache: | 256K | 1024K |
| L3 cache: | 15360K | 33792K |
| NUMA node0 CPU(s): | 0-5 | 0-47 |
| NUMA node0 CPU(s): | 0-47 |  |

Comment: Have you tried [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/debug.html) to identify if there is a particular step that is slow or of this is a general thing? Also if there any possibility that you have limitations at the OS level (e g. number of cores or memory per process). Maybe this question would be more relevant to superuser/server fault than stackoverflow?

Comment: I have not tried profiling. Since my script is basically one line (just a call to plt.subplots), how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Update: our Sys Admin found the issue. There was some sort of timeout happening when using X11 forwarding (ssh -Y). Removing the -Y flag, or changing to -x solved the issue. We found that adding

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

to the script will also solve the slowdown issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I have the same issue with the ssh, which really resolved my issue. I have to log in and upvote for you.